# Linking to an audit table

Tags: sql-server

So I have dbo.Table1 that contains ID, ColA, ColB, ColC.

I also have audit.Table1 that contains AuditID, AuditDate, AuditUserID, AuditType, ID, ColA, ColB, ColC.

AuditType is either I, U, or D (for Insert, Update, or Delete).

The results I'm looking for is a query that I gives me each record in Table1 based on whatever where clauses, but also gives me Last Modified information pulled from the audit.Table1 table (the most recent 'U' value for the ID) mainly I want the date and AuditUserID so I can pull a basic Last Modified on such & such date by so & so user.

I've tried using a Cross Apply, but stopped along that thought when my query was still running after 30 seconds.

There can be instances where there is no 'U' record (the record was only created, no changes have been made).

Comment: Can you post table definitions (create table statements), sample data as insert statements and desired output for the sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after working further on this, I was able to make everything work by creating a transitional left join that just gave me the AuditID # of the last touched entry...  and if the AuditUserID is null from my left join, then I know it hasn't been modified since creation.  So my final query is basically...

```
SELECT [fields wanted from Courses table],
IIF(ISNULL(ac.AuditUserID,0) = 0, [make created by info], [make modified info]) as LastModInfo
FROM dbo.Courses c
    LEFT JOIN (select MAX(AuditID), CourseID from audit.Courses group by CourseID) mid
        ON mid.CourseID = c.CourseID
    LEFT JOIN audit.Course ac on ac.AuditID = mid.AuditID AND ac.AuditType = 'U'
```

Thank you @seanlange for your attempt

Answer (score 1):

It isn't very clear exactly what you have going on here. But pretty sure you can use something along these lines.

```
create table Table1
(
    ID int identity
    , ColA varchar(10)
    , ColB varchar(10)
    , ColC varchar(10)
)

insert Table1
select 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'

insert Table1
select 'This', 'has', 'no update'

create table AuditTable1
(
    AuditID int identity
    , AuditDate datetime
    , AuditUserID int
    , AuditType char(1)
    , ID int
    , ColA varchar(10)
    , ColB varchar(10)
    , ColC varchar(10)
)

insert AuditTable1
select getdate()
    , 9 --just some number
    , 'U'
    , 1
    , 'Col1'
    , 'Col2'
    , 'Col3'

select t.*
    , x.AuditID
    , x.AuditDate
    , x.AuditUserID
from Table1 t
outer apply
(
    select top 1 AuditID
        , AuditDate
        , AuditUserID
    from AuditTable1 at1
    where at1.ID = t.ID
    order by at1.AuditDate desc
) x
```

Comment: My problem with this was that the apply was taking FOREVER (I manually stopped it after 30 seconds).

Comment: Then we probably need to look at the execution plan. Most likely some indexes will help here. Can you get an execution plan and post it? (yeah I know it might take a while to create it) https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ Or post the ddl for your tables and include all the indexes.